# 2 Mutually Exclusive InputComponents Referring to the same Field is updating the same field Twice

Tags: java, jsf, render, visible

I have a screen with `2 JSF Input Components`: `inputText` and `inputText with suggestionBox`. They are both bound to the **same field**, but only one can be visible/rendered (mutual exclusion). 
The thing is that if I write something in one and then submit, the other **component which is not displayed is updating the model** (the same field is updated again) **with** it's value (which is **empty string** or null). To work around this I created another field in my Class, so that the 2 components don't refer to the same field. 
I don't like this, because I'm altering my model to solve a GUI problem.

> How can I have 2 mutually exclusive input
>   components referring the same value
>   working as I want ?

Comment: It should be able to work. When you say "component that is not displayed" I assume you are controlling this with rendered="false"?

Comment: actually is `visible=false`, in ADF Faces. We're not allowed to use rendered for some reason. input texts with visible=false I think are used to pass values through requests not needed in the screen. Any workaround, to get the same behavior like rendered ? visible=false + readonly=true or something like this ?

Comment: I don't know anything about ADF Faces but I can't imagine they would remove support for the rendered attribute. It's rather essential to JSF. I'll research a bit as the problem seems to be that your not truly removing the component from the render phase -- you're just making it invisible.

Comment: the rendered attribute exists, but we can't use it. I know it's rendered in html with some css that makes it hidden.

Comment: why can't you use it? It is what will solve the very problem you are posting about? Do you have a team lead that had a bad childhood experience with it? It is really the only elegant way to solve the problem above (and it's super easy to implement).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I stated I can't use rendered, so in this case using `readonly true` with `visible false` gives me the behavior I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the rendered attribute to show/hide the components so that only one or the other is actually updating the model at a time. Here is a very basic example to illustrate:

```
<h:form id="exampleForm" prependId="false">

    <h:inputText id="test1" value="#{exampleBean.testString}" rendered="#{exampleBean.toggle}" style="border: 1px solid red;" />
    <h:inputText id="test2" value="#{exampleBean.testString}" rendered="#{!exampleBean.toggle}" style="border: 1px solid blue;" />

    <h:commandButton id="testButton" action="#{exampleBean.toggle()}" />

</h:form>
```

and the example bean with shared property `testString`:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "exampleBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ExampleBean {

    private String testString;

    public String getTestString() { return testString; }

    public void setTestString(String testString) { 
        this.testString = testString; 
        System.out.println(testString);
    }

    private boolean toggle;

    public boolean isToggle() { return toggle; }
    public void setToggle(boolean toggle) { this.toggle = toggle; }

    public void toggle() {
        toggle = (toggle) ? false : true;
    }

}
```